# Can I use a join query to do this?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to admit trying to understand JOINs makes my brain explode so I need some help.

What I'm trying to accomplish is return info on the last 25 postings in a forum, but the main posts table only returns numbers for the Topic and Forum, whereas I need the textual names of the topic and forum, which I can retrieve from two other tables.  In my very limited understanding of joins, it seems I can use one to do all of this in a single query rather than coding 3+ queries with loops and other perhaps unneeded code.

This would be the main query:

```
SELECT post_id, topic_id, forum_id, post_time
  FROM posts
  ORDER BY post_id DESC
  LIMIT 25
```

But for each of the 25 results I also want included **forum_title** from table **forums** where **forum_id** in that table matches the **forum_id** from the main query results, as well as **topic_title** from table **topics** where the **topic_id** in that table matches the **topic_id** in the main query results.

I'm hoping just even seeing what this would look like will help my understanding of how JOINs work.

Thanks

EDIT:  I realized I should have used the exact column and table names so that I wouldn't be editing suggestions.  Using the exact names, this is how Aquinas' suggestion would look:

```
SELECT post_id, topic_id, forum_id, post_time, Forum_Title, Topic_Title
  FROM phpbb3_posts 
  INNER JOIN phpbb3_topics
    on phpbb3_topics.topic_id = phpbb3_posts.topic_id
  INNER JOIN phpbb3_forums
    on phpbb3_forums.forum_id = phpbb3_posts.forum_id
  ORDER BY post_id DESC
  LIMIT 25
```

but I get this error (this is in mysql)
1052 - Column 'topic_id' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id, topic_id, forum_id, post_time, Forum_Title, Topic_Title FROM posts 
INNER JOIN topics on topics.topic_id = posts.topic_id
INNER JOIN forums on forums.forum_id = posts.forum_id
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Sorry I should have used the exact field and table names I intended to use, I have updated my main posting.

Comment: Looks like all I had to do was specify phpbb3_posts.topic_id and phpbb3_posts.forum_id in the main select.  Thanks!